# Android disable button on successful doinbackground call

Tags: android, asynchronous, fatal-error

The following code gives Fatal Exception Async Task #2 on the line `v1.setEnabled(false)`.

It means to disable button on successful call. The `v.setEnabled(false);` before background task works fine. Please help :(

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    //this one would work
    //v.setEnabled(false);

    final View v1=v;
    mRegisterTask1 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        boolean success = 
            ServerUtilities.receipt (((String)v1.getTag()).substring(3),"acknowledged");

        if (success) {
            //this one causes Async Task exception
            v1.setEnabled(false);
        } 
        else {
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mRegisterTask1 = null;
    }
```

Comment: And the stack trace is...

Comment: You can't change widgets from `doInBackground` as that method runs on  a background thread. Either use `runOnUiThread` or post a `Runnable` on `v1` with the `post` method to change the state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the ui modification to `onPostExecute`

```
boolean success = false;

protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
      success = ServerUtilities.receipt (((String)v1.getTag()).substring(3),"acknowledged");

        if (success) {
               //this one causes Async Task exception
                 v1.setEnabled(false);
          } else {

           }
                    return null;
             }
@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
      if (success) {
         //this one causes Async Task exception
            v1.setEnabled(false);
        } else {

        }
       mRegisterTask1 = null;
  }
```

Comment: That works! Now could you explain difference between Void and void? (since void did not work...)

Answer (score 5):

You can't change the UI state from background thread.
AsyncTask `onPreExecute()` & `onPostExecute()` methods called in main thread.
Take a look :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
    //this one would work
    //v.setEnabled(false);


    final View v1=v;
    mRegisterTask1 = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            boolean success =
                    ServerUtilities.receipt (((String)v1.getTag()).substring(3),"acknowledged");


            return success;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bolean result) {

        if (result) {
                //this one causes Async Task exception
                v1.setEnabled(false);
            } else {

            }

            mRegisterTask1 = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot make Boolean doInBackground, only Void

Comment: You can set the return parameter of AsyncTask as any Object (Boolean) and not primitives (boolean).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change widgets from the UI thread. The methods `onProgressUpdate` and `OnPostExecute` are executed in the UI therad. So you may consider to move your code to the latter.